# stdin.setRawMode not working after resuming from background

Tags: node.js, stdin

I do `process.stdin.setRawMode(true)` and I get data on every keypress.  Then I do `process.kill(process.pid, 'SIGSTOP')` and put the process into the background.  When I resume the process with linux `$ fg` I no longer get data on every keypress but only after a carriage return.  Calling `setRawMode(true)` again has no effect.  I think this must be a bug?

Answer (score 1):

Probably not very many people want to use nodejs for its raw mode processing but I posted the issue on the nodejs github and they said a work around is to `setRawMode(false)` and then `setRawMode(true)` since it will not work just setting it to true again.

Comment: [Time machine sounds] chiming in from 2023 to say this was a lifesaver. I'm writing a text editor in Node.js and as an old school Unix guy I still appreciate control-z sometimes.